# Adding column to worksheet in Excel with OLEDB

Tags: excel, oledb

Hello
I'm trying to add new column to the Excel worksheet by command

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD COLUMN Field_dest nvarchar

But on execution of the command got exception "Invalid operation"
I tried table name with and without $ at the end , but got the same result
My questions are
1) Is there some wrong in the command above?
2) Is command ALTER table supported for excel table ?
3) Is the alternative way to add column into excel worksheet - preferable via OLEDB ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter table will not work, AFAIK, however, you can Create Table or Select Into, which will allow you to create a new sheet. I cannot get this to run against an open sheet.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim scn As String
Dim sSQL As String

strFile = "C:\Docs\test.xls"

scn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"""

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open scn

''Note that there is no $ on the sheet to be created
sSQL = "SELECT *,'' As NewField INTO [Sheet17] FROM [Sheet4$]"

''Jet data types
sSQL = "CREATE TABLE [Sheet8] (AText text, ANother text)"

cn.Execute sSQL
```

If you run against an open file, you will get an error to the effect that Sheetn does not exist.

Comment: @lm I think I failed to explain. You cannot add to an existing table, but you can copy the existing table with a new column into a new sheet, `SELECT *,'' As NewField INTO [Sheet17] FROM [Sheet4$]` where Sheet4$ is the existing table, * is all the columns, '' As NewField is an additional column and Sheet17 is the new table. Alternatively, you can create a new table with CREATE TABLE and update it with the existing data.

Comment: I understand . I will check option to use SELECT ..INTO ( As you explained ) or another to create table with updated structure before . Thanks a lot for useful information .

Comment: Hi, I am looking for solution for this similar problem. I have used select into to create a copy, but once the data is copied when I try to open the excel file, i get error as excel file is corrupted. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @coolcake All I can think of without a code sample is that you may not have the right connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Create Table instead of Alter Table.
Just use your existing table name, then your columns adds to existing sheet

```
CREATE TABLE [ExistingSheet$] (ID char(255), oldField1 char(255), newField2 char(255))
```

it's work!